# Check if URL protocol exists on PC

Tags: php, protocols, verifone

I am building a POS system, with a link to a VeriFone device. To talk to the VeriFone, I am using a custom built URL protocol. Now I need a way to check if the protocol even exists on the local computer that's using the POS.

What would be the best way of doing such a thing? The POS is programmed in basic web languages (PHP, Jquery, Javascript), the connection to the VeriFone device is programmed in PHP, too. Any help for even just suggestions where to look (If PHP even has it, or any other language) is very welcome.

Comment: Could you please explain what is that POS you are referring to? Thanks.

Comment: @Jinksy POS stands for Point of sale, a cashregister that's working on a browser.

Comment: BTW. URL is not a protocol. :)

Comment: @Jinksy I have my own protocol, which means it acts like a URL, but launches something locally (In my case it launches a local program), side note, I never said that URL is a protocol

Comment: You are right, it would seem that I've misunderstood the whole question. Sorry about that.